# Converting numeric data to binary format

Tags: algorithm, binary, neural-network

Is there any way to convert numeric data to binary equivalent for giving input to neural networks

Checked in **weka**- "Converts all numeric attributes into binary attributes (apart from the class attribute, if set): if the value of the numeric attribute is exactly zero, the value of the new attribute will be zero. If the value of the numeric attribute is missing, the value of the new attribute will be missing. Otherwise, the value of the new attribute will be one. The new attributes will be nominal."

Checked in **RapidMiner**- "they are using 2 parameters for convertion min and max values.If the value of an attribute is between the specified minimal and maximal value, it becomes 'false', otherwise 'true'
"

Can anyone tell me a better way to convert numeric data to binary.

sample data

```
10,50,35,15
15,20,70,25
25,10,55,10
55,10,35,15
35,15,10,50
20,25,15,20
7,55,25,30
8,35,25,30
9,70,55,10
```

Or whether neural networks is capable of taking numeric data as input?

Comment: Do you want **string** binary representation of given integers? Like `35 => "0b100011"` ?

Comment: 4-->10, 100->1010 these are binary equivalent for numeric values but after converting I am not able to supply them to Neural networks(as after binary convertion the data becomes nominal)..any workaround

Comment: What do the values represent? If you really want to convert the input to binary attributes, you probably want to use categories such as small, large, medium, very large. That said, Neural networks should also work with numeric floating point input normalized to a range between 0 and 1.